Flower framework server not execute a evaluate function
I have implemented a federated AI model with flower and it seems to work almost fine. The server starts correctly and its clients appear to connect and train correctly. There is only one problem, it seems that the server is unable to call the eveluate function, what am I doing wrong? below is the server, client and main code (there are a few code comments that I tried to resolve), furthermore logging doesn't seem to help as it doesn't save anything in the file
SERVER.py
from typing import Dict, List, Optional, Tuple
import flwr as fl
from flwr.common import Metrics

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

import Plotter
from Utils import Utils

from torchvision import datasets
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor, Normalize, Compose
import torch
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import DataLoader
from collections import OrderedDict

from src_torch.FlowerClient import get_client_fn

class Server:
    ROUNDS_NUMBER = 1
    BATCH_SIZE = 100

    def __init__(self, utils: Utils) -> None:
        self.utils = utils
        Utils.printLog('server starting')

        self.model = utils.get_model()
        self.model_parameters = [val.cpu().numpy() for _, val in self.model.state_dict().items()]

        self.accuracy_data = []
        self.loss_data = []

        self.plotter = Plotter.Plotter(self.utils.dataset_name, Server.ROUNDS_NUMBER, self.utils.poisoning,
                                       self.utils.blockchain)

        self.test_data = self.get_test_data()

        self.strategy = fl.server.strategy.FedAvg(
            # fraction_fit=1.0,
            # fraction_evaluate=1.0,
            min_fit_clients=self.utils.CLIENTS_NUM,
            min_evaluate_clients=Utils.CLIENTS_NUM,
            min_available_clients=self.utils.CLIENTS_NUM,
            evaluate_fn=self.get_evaluate_fn(),
            # on_fit_config_fn=self.fit_config(),
            # on_evaluate_config_fn=self.evaluate_config(),
            initial_parameters=fl.common.ndarrays_to_parameters(self.model_parameters),
        )

    def get_test_data(self):
        stats = ((0.5), (0.5)) if self.utils.dataset_name == 'mnist' else ((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
        test_transform = Compose([
            ToTensor(),
            Normalize(*stats)
        ])

        if self.utils.dataset_name == 'cifar100':
            test_data = datasets.CIFAR100(
                root=Utils.DATASET_PATH,
                train=False,
                download=True,
                transform=test_transform
            )
        elif self.utils.dataset_name == 'cifar10':
            test_data = datasets.CIFAR10(
                root=Utils.DATASET_PATH,
                train=False,
                download=True,
                transform=test_transform
            )
        else:
            test_data = datasets.MNIST(
                root=Utils.DATASET_PATH,
                train=False,
                download=True,
                transform=test_transform
            )
            # serve?
            # self.train_data.data = self.train_data.data.reshape(self.train_data.data.shape[0],self.train_data.data.shape[1], self.train_data.data.shape[2],1)
        return test_data

    def fit_config(self, server_round: int):
        """Return training configuration dict for each round.

        Keep batch size fixed at 32, perform two rounds of training with one local epoch,
        increase to two local epochs afterwards.
        """
        config = {
            "batch_size": Server.BATCH_SIZE,
            "local_epochs": 1 if server_round < 2 else 2,
        }
        return config

    def evaluate_config(self, server_round: int):
        """Return evaluation configuration dict for each round.

        Perform five local evaluation steps on each client (i.e., use five batches) during
        rounds one to three, then increase to ten local evaluation steps.
        """
        val_steps = 5 if server_round < 4 else 10
        return {"val_steps": val_steps}

    def get_evaluate_fn(self):
        """Return an evaluation function for server-side evaluation."""

        # model = self.model
        # utils = self.utils
        # test_data_loader = DataLoader(self.test_data, batch_size=16)
        test_data_loader = DataLoader(self.test_data, batch_size=Server.BATCH_SIZE)

        # The `evaluate` function will be called after every round
        def evaluate(
                server_round: int,
                parameters: fl.common.NDArrays,
                config: Dict[str, fl.common.Scalar],
        ) -> Optional[Tuple[float, Dict[str, fl.common.Scalar]]]:
            # Update model with the latest parameters
            Utils.printLog('--------------------------\n its work \n ------------------------------')
            params_dict = zip(self.model.state_dict().keys(), parameters)
            state_dict = OrderedDict({k: torch.tensor(v) for k, v in params_dict})
            self.model.load_state_dict(state_dict, strict=True)

            loss, accuracy = self.test(test_data_loader)

            self.accuracy_data.append(accuracy)
            self.loss_data.append(loss)
            if server_round == (Server.ROUNDS_NUMBER - 1):
                self.plotter.line_chart_plot(self.accuracy_data, self.loss_data)
                self.set_confusion_matrix(test_data_loader)
            return loss, {"accuracy": accuracy}

            # """Validate the network on the entire test set."""
            # print("Starting evalutation server...")
            # self.model.to(device)  # move model to GPU if available
            # self.model.eval()
            #
            # criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
            # correct, loss = 0, 0.0
            #
            # test_data_loader = DataLoader(self.test_data, batch_size=Server.BATCH_SIZE)
            #
            # with torch.no_grad():
            #     for batch in test_data_loader:
            #         images, labels = batch
            #         images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
            #         outputs = self.model(images)
            #         loss += criterion(outputs, labels).item()
            #         _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            #         correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
            # accuracy = correct / len(test_data_loader.dataset)
            #
            # self.accuracy_data.append(accuracy)
            # self.loss_data.append(loss)
            # if server_round == Server.ROUNDS_NUMBER:
            #     self.plotter.line_chart_plot(self.accuracy_data, self.loss_data)
            #     self.set_confusion_matrix(test_data_loader)
            #
            # return loss, accuracy

    def test(self, test_data_loader):
        """Validate the network on the entire test set."""
        print("Starting evalutation...")
        device: torch.device = torch.device("cpu")
        self.model.to(device)  # move model to GPU if available
        criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        correct, loss = 0, 0.0
        self.model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(test_data_loader):
                images, labels = batch["img"], batch["label"]
                images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
                outputs = self.model(images)
                loss += criterion(outputs, labels).item()
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
        accuracy = correct / len(test_data_loader.dataset)
        # self.model.to("cpu")  # move model back to CPU
        return loss, accuracy

    @staticmethod
    def weighted_average(metrics: List[Tuple[int, Metrics]]) -> Metrics:
        # Aggregation function for (federated) evaluation metrics, i.e. those returned by
        # the client's evaluate() method.
        # Multiply accuracy of each client by number of examples used
        accuracies = [num_examples * m["accuracy"] for num_examples, m in metrics]
        examples = [num_examples for num_examples, _ in metrics]

        # Aggregate and return custom metric (weighted average)
        return {"accuracy": sum(accuracies) / sum(examples)}

    def set_confusion_matrix(self, test_data_loader: torch.utils.data.DataLoader):
        y_true = []
        y_pred = []
        for inputs, labels in test_data_loader:
            output = self.model(inputs)  # Feed Network

            output = (torch.max(torch.exp(output), 1)[1]).data.cpu().numpy()
            y_pred.extend(output)  # Save Prediction

            labels = labels.data.cpu().numpy()
            y_true.extend(labels)  # Save Truth

        result = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
        self.plotter.confusion_matrix_chart_plot(result)

    # @staticmethod
    # def set_confusion_matrix(model, model_conf, plotter):
    #     y_predict = model.predict(model_conf.x_test)
    #     y_predict = np.argmax(y_predict, axis=1)
    #     y_test = np.argmax(model_conf.y_test, axis=1)
    #     result = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predict)
    #     plotter.confusion_matrix_chart_plot(result)

    def start_server(self):
        # Start Flower server for four rounds of federated learning
        print("Starting server flower...")
        fl.server.start_server(
            server_address="0.0.0.0:8080",
            config=fl.server.ServerConfig(num_rounds=Server.ROUNDS_NUMBER),
            strategy=self.strategy,
        )

    def start_simulation(self):
        # client_resources = {"num_cpus": 2, "num_gpus": 0.5}
        fl.simulation.start_simulation(
            client_fn=get_client_fn(self.utils),
            num_clients=self.utils.CLIENTS_NUM,
            config=fl.server.ServerConfig(num_rounds=Server.ROUNDS_NUMBER),
            strategy=self.strategy,
            # client_resources=client_resources,
        )


CLIENT.py
import flwr as fl

from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

# import Utils

from Utils import Utils
import pickle
import os
import torch
from torch.utils.data.dataset import Subset

from collections import OrderedDict
from tqdm import tqdm

class FlowerClient(fl.client.NumPyClient):

    def __init__(self, utils: Utils, cid: int) -> None:
        self.utils = utils
        self.cid = cid
        Utils.printLog(f'initializing client{self.cid}')

        self.device = torch.device(
            "cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
        )

        self.model = self.utils.get_model()
        self.epochs = 1 if self.utils.dataset_name != 'mnist' else 1
        self.batch_size = 100
        self.client_partition_data: Subset
        with open(os.path.join(f"../data/partitions/{self.utils.dataset_name}",
                               f"partition_{0}.pickle"), "rb") as f:
            self.client_partition_data = pickle.load(f)

        train_data_size = int(0.9 * len(self.client_partition_data))  # 90% for training
        test_data_size = len(self.client_partition_data) - train_data_size
        self.train_data, self.test_data = torch.utils.data.random_split(self.client_partition_data,
                                                                        [train_data_size, test_data_size])

        # self.steps_for_epoch = len(self.x_train) // self.batch_size
        # self.verbose = 0

        self.train_data_loader = DataLoader(self.test_data, batch_size=self.batch_size, shuffle=True)
        self.test_data_loader = DataLoader(self.test_data, batch_size=self.batch_size)

        if utils.poisoning and (self.cid in utils.POISONERS_CLIENTS_CID):
            self.run_poisoning()


    def run_poisoning(self):
        self.utils.printLog(f'client {self.cid} starting poisoning')
        # self.y_train = np.random.permutation(self.y_train)
        for batch in self.train_data_loader:
            img, labels = batch
            labels = labels[torch.randperm(labels.size(0))]  # label flipping
            img = self.add_perturbation(img)

    def add_perturbation(self, img):
        scale = 0.8
        noise = torch.randn(img.shape) * scale
        perturbed_img = img + noise

        return perturbed_img

    def set_parameters(self, parameters):
        """Loads model and replaces it parameters with the
        ones given."""
        params_dict = zip(self.model.state_dict().keys(), parameters)
        state_dict = OrderedDict({k: torch.tensor(v) for k, v in params_dict})
        self.model.load_state_dict(state_dict, strict=True)

    def fit(self, parameters, config):
        """Train parameters on the locally held training set."""

        # Update local model parameters
        self.set_parameters(parameters)

        # Get hyperparameters for this round
        # batch_size: int = config["batch_size"]
        # epochs: int = config["local_epochs"]

        results = self.train()

        parameters_prime = self.get_model_params()
        num_examples_train = len(self.train_data)

        return parameters_prime, num_examples_train, results

    def train(self):
        """Train the network on the training set."""
        print("Starting training...")
        self.model.to(self.device)  # move model to GPU if available
        criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(self.device)
        optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(
            self.model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=1e-4
        )

        self.model.train()
        for epoch in range(self.epochs):
            running_loss = 0.0
            correct = 0
            total = 0

            progress_bar = tqdm(enumerate(self.train_data_loader), total=len(self.test_data_loader))
            for batch_idx, (images, labels) in progress_bar:
                # images, labels = batch["img"], batch["label"]
                images, labels = images.to(self.device), labels.to(self.device)
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss = criterion(self.model(images), labels)
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()

                running_loss += loss.item()
                _, predicted = self.model(images).max(1)
                total += labels.size(0)
                correct += predicted.eq(labels).sum().item()

                progress_bar.set_description(
                    f'Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{self.epochs}], Train Loss: {running_loss / (batch_idx + 1):.4f}, Train Acc: {100. * correct / total:.2f}%')

        self.model.to("cpu")  # move model back to CPU

        train_loss, train_acc = self.test(self.train_data_loader)
        val_loss, val_acc = self.test(self.test_data_loader)

        results = {
            "train_loss": train_loss,
            "train_accuracy": train_acc,
            "val_loss": val_loss,
            "val_accuracy": val_acc,
        }
        return results

    def test(self,data_loader):
        """Validate the network on the entire test set."""
        print(f"Starting evalutation client{self.cid}...")
        device: torch.device = torch.device("cpu")
        self.model.to(device)  # move model to GPU if available
        criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        correct, loss = 0, 0.0
        self.model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            for batch in data_loader:
                images, labels = batch
                images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
                outputs = self.model(images)
                loss += criterion(outputs, labels).item()
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
        accuracy = correct / len(data_loader.dataset)
        # print(
        #     f'Epoch [{self.epochs + 1}/{self.epochs}], Train Loss: {loss:.4f}, Train Acc: {100. * correct / total:.2f}%, Val Loss: {val_loss:.4f}, Val Acc: {accuracy:.2f}%')
        print(f'Val Loss: {loss:.4f}, Val Acc: {accuracy:.2f}%')
        # self.model.to("cpu")  # move model back to CPU
        return loss, accuracy

    def get_model_params(self):
        """Returns a model's parameters."""
        return [val.cpu().numpy() for _, val in self.model.state_dict().items()]

    def evaluate(self, parameters, config):
        Utils.printLog(f'client {self.cid} evaluating model')
        """Evaluate parameters on the locally held test set."""
        # Update local model parameters
        self.set_parameters(parameters)

        # Get config values
        # steps: int = config["val_steps"]

        # Evaluate global model parameters on the local test data and return results
        # testloader = DataLoader(self.testset, batch_size=16)

        loss, accuracy = self.test(self.test_data_loader)

        # print(
        #     f'Epoch [{self.epochs + 1}/{self.epochs}], Train Loss: {loss:.4f}, Train Acc: {100. * correct / total:.2f}%, Val Loss: {val_loss:.4f}, Val Acc: {accuracy:.2f}%')
        print(
            f'Val Loss: {loss:.4f}, Val Acc: {accuracy:.2f}%')

        return float(loss), len(self.test_data), {"accuracy": float(accuracy)}

    def start_client(self):
        # client = CifarClient(trainset, testset, device, args.model).to_client()
        fl.client.start_client(server_address="127.0.0.1:8080", client=self.to_client())




def get_client_fn(model_conf):
    def client_fn(cid: str) -> fl.client.Client:
       return FlowerClient(model_conf, int(cid))

    return client_fn




MAIN.py
DEFAULT_FORMATTER = logging.Formatter(
"%(levelname)s %(name)s %(asctime)s | %(filename)s:%(lineno)d | %(message)s"
)
fl.common.logger.configure(identifier="executionLog", filename="log.txt")

utils = Utils.Utils('cifar100', 100, (3, 3), (32, 32, 3), True, False)


def start_server():
    server = Server.Server(utils)
    # Start Flower server for four rounds of federated learning
    # print("Starting server flowe...")
    # fl.server.start_server(
    #     server_address="0.0.0.0:8080",
    #     config=fl.server.ServerConfig(num_rounds=Server.Server.ROUNDS_NUMBER),
    #     strategy=server.strategy,
    # )
    server.start_server()


def start_client(cid):
    print("clien{cid} start".format(cid=cid))
    client = FlowerClient.FlowerClient(utils, cid)
    # fl.client.start_client(server_address="127.0.0.1:8080", client=client)
    client.start_client()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # start_server()
    serverThread = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_server).start()
    # time.sleep(5)
    # for i in range(utils.CLIENTS_NUM):
    #     clientThread = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_client, args=[i]).start()


    # server=Server.Server(utils)
    # server.start_simulation()

